# magento custom module controller can't get the toHtml() function

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

My custom module is a payment gateaway, i have a redirect controller and here is the script

```
class Asurepay_Custompay_AsurepayController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    protected $_order;

    public function getOrder() {
        if ($this->_order == null) {

        }
        return $this->_order;
    }

    public function indexAction(){
        echo "index test 1";
    }

    public function redirectAction(){
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $session->setAsurepayCustompayQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('asurepay/redirect')->toHtml());
        $session->unsQuoteId();
        $session->unsRedirectUrl();
    }

}
```

The function **redirectAction()** can't get the toHtml() function

and here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in my code
```

what should be the error of this? I have a block in **ModuleName/Block/Redirect.php** and I have a toHtml(). or what should be the cause of error?

**REQUESTED**

Here is my redirect block located at **ModuleName/Block/Redirect.php**

```
class Asurepay_Custompay_Block_Standard_Redirect extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract {

    protected function _toHtml() {

        $asure = Mage::getModel("custompay/asure");
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $form->setAction($standard->getConfig()->getGateurl)
            ->setId('asurepay_custompay_checkout')
            ->setName('asurepay_custompay_checkout')
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setUseContainer(true);

        foreach ($standard->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() as $field=>$value) {
            $form->addField($field, 'hidden', array('name'=>$field, 'value'=>$value, 'size'=>200));
        }
        $html = '<html><body>';
        $html.= $this->__('You will be redirected to AsurePay in a few seconds.');
        $html.= $form->toHtml();
        $html.= '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("asurepay_checkout").submit();</script>';
        $html.= '</body></html>';
        return $html;

    }
}
```

Comment: could you show us the block class, xml layout and phtml template? I think this could be usefull to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->loadLayout();
```

At that point blocks are not loaded yet. You have to call load layout and only after you will be able to access blocks defined in layout.

Comment: That's true, but he's also trying to create the block himself, not loading one from the predefined layout. If you discovered that $this->getLayout()->createBlock() couldn't work without loadLayout, I'd be more convinced :)

Comment: how can i do this? the page is for redirect. does it need a .phtml file? or do you have suggested link for me to study?

Comment: Just try to call $this->loadLayout() before creating block. In $this->getLayout() layout will be instantiated and returned, but will not be configured properly. Layout handlers are initialized in loadLayout()

Comment: You don't need to loadLayout before creating a block. The layout object clready exists by the time you get to the controller action The loadLayout method will pull together the package layout, parse it down to to the page layout, and then create block from the page layout.  If you wanted to create a block and then ADD it to the existing layout, you'd need to call loadLayout before adding your block.  However, if all you want to do is manually create a block and then instantiate it, there's no need.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the line that's causing you a problem

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('asurepay/redirect')->toHtml()
```

Let's rewrite that using non-chained syntax to take things a little me clear

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$block  = $layout->createBlock('asurepay/redirect');
$html   = $block->toHtml();
```

When PHP complains with

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in my code
```

It's saying that the `$block` variable (the results of the call to `createBlock`) is not an object.  That means your call to `createBlock` has failed for some reason.

My educated guess here is you're `config.xml` file is setup incorrectly.  Based on your block class name (`Asurepay_Custompay_Block_Standard_Redirect`) and standard conventions in `config.xml`, your alias should be

```
$layout->createBlock('custompay/standard_redirect');
```

However, that assumes a `config.xml` setup something like

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <custompay>
                <class>Asurepay_Custompay_Block</class>
            </custompay>                
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <!-- ... -->
</config>
```

If you post the contents of your `config.xml` people will be able to diagnose your problem.